# Jquery tooltip attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using tooltip plugin and i'm trying to show tooltip on DOM element hover.
I'm injecting tooltip attribute to the DOM element with:

```
$(e.target).attr('tooltip', "Some value");
$(e.target).attr('tooltip-popup-delay', 500);
```

The attributes are added to the element but tooltip is not displayed when element is hovered over. I have a feeling that it has something to do with the way i inject the attribute to the element. Any ideas?

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: i think its ui-bootstrap plugin for angular.js

Comment: Any news about this ?